# Exclude file types with Bitcasa

Tags: backup, online-backup, exclude

Is there any way to exclude certain file types from being mirrored with Bitcasa? I have a lot of Lightroom catalogues to backup, and want to exclude all the preview files (*.lrprev), as it's just a waste of bandwidth to backup 100K plus such files.

Bitcasa doesn't provide any support for users on the free plan (which I'm on to evaluate it before signing up for a paid plan!), so I can't just ask their support people!

Comment: Not what your asking, but I'd recommend not using Bitcasa at all. They have [proven to be unreliable](http://www.reddit.com/r/bitcasa/comments/2k6qj3/class_action_against_bitcasa/). (Like they wiped my data without alerting me, after which their helpdesk hell was not useful either.) Amazon [offers unlimited](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive) for $60/year.

Comment: @Arjan I never did figure this out, and the lack of support from Bitcasa was a problem too. I also read a lot of negative things about them online and eventually went with Dropbox